# Send form with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with validation but have a trouble when try submit form.

How to call **usr.php?reset** correctly?

Here HTML

```
  <form id="register" class="horizontal-form">
  ... ... ...
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
```

Here JQUERY

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
  success3.show();
  error3.hide();
  $.post('usr.php?resetpw');
  form[0].submit(); // submit the form
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up two different ways to do the same thing.

`$.post` sends a POST ajax request (and doesn't need the form to submit).  Currently you're not listening for any response, so usr.php?resetpw is being called but the results are not shown to the user.

`form[0].submit()` tries to submit the form, but because there's no "action" attribute on the form tag, there's nowhere to submit it to, so it doesn't.

If you intend to refresh the whole window with whatever usr.php?resetpw returns, make that the action of the form and remove the `$.post`.

If you intend to make an ajax call (and I'm guessing based on the rest of the submit handler that this is what you want), remove the nonoperative `form[0].submit` and add something to handle the results of the [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post( "usr.php?resetpw", function( data ) {
  // do something with data here
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your time.